# excluding a specified category into a latest post

Tags: wordpress

I use this code to display my latest post.

```
<?php get_archives('postbypost', '10', 'custom', '<li>', '</li>'); ?>
```

but i want to alter it to my needs so what i want is to exclude the post that has a category of 'testimonials'. Precisely, what i want is, I dont like to display the post that has a category of 'testimonials' in my latest post.

Im currently searching on the net for that approach but unfortunately, nothing found so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think `get_archives` has been deprecated. The replacement `wp_get_archives` does not natively allow you to exclude categories.

So it might be worth considering the use of `get_posts`. An example can be found on:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Latest_posts_ordered_by_title

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <div>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

So if you are only showing each post name in a `<li></li>` list format, you might (without testing this) be able to try - where 3 is the ID of testimonials -

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'category__not_in' => array(3));
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
    <li>
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
    </li>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```